# Jmeter concurrent users

Tags: jmeter

I've realised there seems to be a lot of confusion around `Number of threads(users)` My question is what exactly does the word 'users' refer to in JMeter?

According to the documentation:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group

`Multiple threads are used to simulate concurrent connections to your server application.`

To me this seems to be referring to the number of requests that are made to a server and not an individual user who could make any number of requests.

Can someone clarify if 'Users' refers to an individual user or the number of requests that are made. For example, in JMeter how would this be simulated:

1 user requests a webpage which consists of:

- index.html
- styles.css
- bg.jpg

Now is this considered 1 user or 3 users (1 per resource requested)?

Comment: Does this help ? https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping should be very simple

```
1 thread == 1 virtual user == 1 real user
```

The only thing you need is to design your test keeping in mind that JMeter's virtual user should act like a real user, including handling these images and styles like `styles.css` and `bg.jpg`, [cookies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), [headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), [cache](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager), [think times](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers), etc.

In regards to web testing and correctly handling CSS and images, real browsers act as follows:

1. Request to main page, i.e. `index.html`
2. **Parallel** requests to all entities included in the main page (images, scripts, styles)

So this is still one user. See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) article for more detailed explanation and recommendations.